# Delphi application and ODBC driver - best practices. Load large amount of data and kill application

Tags: delphi, odbc, delphi-2006

I have an application which is using the ODBC driver. It is more or less build by following this small tutorial http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25639.

My question is: let's say that I'm asking from database to bring in application almost 100k records through a query. But, before I got the results the application will be closed (software design which is not made by me). What's happening with the ODBC driver? It will freeze? Memory used by the driver will increase? How should I manage this 'potential' problem, if exists?

Comment: I just don't get it..+1,-1,-1..no answers, no a given a reason for -1...strange policy for downvoting on SO!

Comment: You're getting -1 votes because your question is extremely vague. It's not clear what you're asking at all; in fact, it's not even clear what you're trying to do or what problem you're trying to solve. You might want to edit to improve the description of what's not working right and what exactly you're asking. Also, posting links to code on external sites (even if they're EDN ones) isn't useful, because people don't want to go somewhere else to try and figure out what the issue might be. You also might want to consider that while you're editing. :)

Comment: Most likely answer is to read the technical details on your particular ODBC driver. The answer will be implementation specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand if the problem you are asking about is one you've experienced (freezing, memory increase) or just one you are asking and in any case the answer probably depends on the ODBC driver and database. If you are half way through retrieving a large result-set and simply call SQLFreeStmt(SQL_CLOSE) what happens next will depend on the ODBC driver and database. Some ODBC drivers talk to the database using a protocol which is synchronous and it may not be possible for the ODBC driver to inform the database it no longer needs any more rows - they just get sent and as the ODBC driver does not know what you are going to do next, it will have to read all that data but throw it away (which may be seen as a pause especially when the result-set is large). Some may be able to send some sort of signal to the database saying stop sending rows.

Either way, at the end as the application is closed memory use is neither here or there. It is good practise to try and tidy up when your app is closed but it shouldn't really matter unless the driver creates some system resources which are not cleared up properly.

Comment: I have not experienced something like this. Just wanted to know what is happening if I'm killing the application before the data is 'moved' into application's memory space.